# How to make text in a tkinter Entry widget stay to the right of the widget instead of the left?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Normally, in a Tkinter Entry widget, your text entered is written from the left to the right. How can I make the text entered into a widget aligned to the right?

Comment: Add `justify='right'` to the creation of the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `entry = Entry(root, justify = RIGHT)`